# Replace variable with other variable in php

Tags: php

I have this variable;

```
$config['base_url'] = 'sudoku.com';
```

I have a problem how to replace 'sudoku.com' with other string when the script found `$config['base_url']`.

The `$config['base_url']` put in other file. and the replacement word in other file.

Comment: Include both file and replace it using `str_replace` or `preg_replace`

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
include "script/that/contains/$config['base_url'];
include "script/that/contains/replacement;

$config['base_url"] = $replacement;
```